# Fire a function when element loses attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to fire a function when element loses some *custom* attribute? For example, when `custom_attribute` is removed, then show me some alert. What's the way to do it? Plain JS is preferable, although jQuery is also okay.

```
<div class="someclass" custom_attribute>...</div>
```

Comment: You better have a look at the concept `mutation observer` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: how would you describe _losing attribute_? On what occasion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('.someclass');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    fire_function();
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

This fires the `fire_function()` every time an attribute is **changed**. So you can check, if the particular attribute is missing or changed.